# Processing intermediate results in MySQL stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I try to do a little weighting of my data by using a stored procedure. Basically this means multiplying certain columns with their respective weights and adding them up in the end.

I have written the following stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test ()  
BEGIN
DECLARE w1 DOUBLE;
DECLARE w2 DOUBLE;
DECLARE res1 DOUBLE;
DECLARE res2 DOUBLE;
DECLARE finres DOUBLE;
SELECT weight1 INTO w1 FROM weights;
SELECT weight2 INTO w2 FROM weights;
SELECT w1 * var1 INTO res1 FROM vartable;
SELECT w2 * var2 INTO res1 FROM vartable;
SELECT res1+res2 INTO finres;
SELECT MEAN(finres);
END
//
```

Unfortunately it does not do the trick yet. In the end it should return one value, but all of this only works if i put all the vars to the SELECT query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it ! The following does work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test2 (IN period1 INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE x1 DOUBLE;
DECLARE x2 DOUBLE;
DECLARE param1 DOUBLE; 
SELECT wvalue INTO x1 FROM weights WHERE uid=1;
SELECT wvalue INTO x2 FROM weights WHERE uid=2;

SELECT x1*x2 INTO param1;
INSERT result_table(result,period) SELECT param1,period1;

END
//
DELIMITER ;

call test2 (@la);
```

Can I store this result somehow? EDIT: figured that one out, too. Store it in some existing table, see edit.

Answer (score 0):

According to [mysql docu](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-procedure.html) you have to declare the parameter you like to output

Like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT)
```

store the value in param1 and call the procedure with:

```
CALL simpleproc(@a);
```

and get the value with:

```
SELECT @a;
```

That should do the trick

Comment: I selected the value INTO param1. Creating the stored procedure did not cause errors too but the @ remains NULL. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, messed up with my first answer, didn't understand the problem ....

You want to calculate the MEAN over your weights multiplied with the variables. But in your procedure you only store doubles. So your MEAN calculation goes over one double. IMHO that makes no sense. E.g. The MEAN of 5 ? :-)

What is written in your tables? Only one row of weights and one row of variables?

Comment: :) yup, mean of a scalar is not that clever... I have data in my datatable and weights in a weight table. Now I´d like to multiply column1 of the data with weight1 and so forth. Afterwards I´d like to sum (weightedcol1 +weightedcol2) which returns a vector. The last step is to AVG(result) - yes AVG is correct not mean :) - and then return AVG(result)

Comment: you mean like:
select AVG(weight1*var1 + weight2*var2) from weights, vartable;

And why not do it in a select?

Comment: In fact the weighting scheme is more complicated than described. 
w1 * d1 = data1
w2 * d2 = data2
w3 * d3 = data3
w4 * d4 = data4
w5 * d5 = data5

intermediate1 = data1
intermediate2 = data2 + data5
intermediate3 = data3 + data4

result = intermediate1 *w6 + intermediate2*w7 + intermediate3*w8

:) All I want is result to be returned.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure how easy it is to store vectors/sets in a procedure and to work with them. I would try to do all the vector/set stuff in database queries and store just scalars in variables of the procedure. If it is possible in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
SELECT AVG(W.weight1 * V.var1 + W.weight2 * V.var2) FROM weights W, vars V;
```

Comment: The queries will get really ugly like that because i have to get weight1 with something like: SELECT weight FROM weights WHERE uid=1